# Access MacBook camera using C# and Xamarin.Mac forms on Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.mac

I need to integrate a video stream from my Macbook camera using a Xamarin.Mac form. However, all of the documentation that I find only tells you how to do so in iOS and Android platforms.

How would you go at getting a video stream from a Macbook then? Any libraries I should look at?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will want to review the `AVFoundation` APIs (`QTKit` is deprecated).

You can create a custom Xamarin.Forms View renderer based on a `NSView` and assign the `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` as the control's layer to stream the camera output to this control.

Store class level references to following and make sure you `Dispose` them when your control goes out of scope otherwise there will be leaks:

```
AVCaptureDevice device;
AVCaptureDeviceInput input;
AVCaptureStillImageOutput output;
AVCaptureSession session;
```

In your capture setup, you can grab the default AV device assuming you want to use the build-in FaceTime Camera (also known as `iSight`).

macOS/Forms Example:

```
device = AVCaptureDevice.GetDefaultDevice(AVMediaTypes.Video);
input = AVCaptureDeviceInput.FromDevice(device, out var error);
if (error == null)
{
    session = new AVCaptureSession();
    session.AddInput(input);
    session.SessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.PresetPhoto;
    var previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.FromSession(session);
    previewLayer.Frame = Control.Bounds;
    Control.Layer = previewLayer;
    output = new AVCaptureStillImageOutput();
    session.AddOutput(output);
    session.StartRunning();
}
```

[image]

Note: A lot of the `AVFoundation` framework is shared between iOS and MacOS, but there are some differences so if you end up looking at iOS sample code be aware you might need to alter it for macOS.

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation

Comment: Hi SushiHangover, do you have a github repo or something for your source code ? I am new to xamarin would be nice to have some sample to follow. Thanks

Comment: @Yini I doubt I still have that example around after 1.5 years, but if I find it later, I'll send you another comment...

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to do up a hack myself see how it goes.

Comment: hey thanks for looking into it. I've decided to install windows on Mac and access webcam from there.

Comment: Would be great to have this solution implemented in Xamarin.Forms.macOS

Comment: @AmirNo-Family That code sample was from a Xamarin.Forms project, using a custom Forms' View renderer.